# Table with foreign key won't compile (no matching unique or primary key for this column-list)

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I've create two tables with some columns and all that stuff. And I get the error "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list", but I've no clue what I am missing...

It's a basic primary and foreign keys tables and it won't compile. I have check on internet for hours and found out nothing.

```
create table TP2_ITEM_FAVORI (
    NOM_UTILISATEUR varchar2(30) not null,
    NO_ITEM number(6) not null,
    constraint PK_ITEM_FAV primary key(NOM_UTILISATEUR, NO_ITEM));

create table TP2_UTILISATEUR (
    NOM_UTILISATEUR varchar2(30) not null,
    NO_ENCAN number(6) not null,
    MOT_DE_PASSE_UTI varchar(30) not null,
    NOM_UTI varchar2(20) not null,
    PRENOM_UTI varchar2(20) not null,
    TEL_UTI char(13) not null,
    COURRIEL_UTI varchar2(25) not null,
    TYPE_UTI varchar(20) not null,
    NOM_UTILISATEUR_PARENT varchar2(30) not null,
    constraint PK_UTILISATEUR primary key(NOM_UTILISATEUR),
    constraint AK_NOM_PRENOM_TEL_UTI unique(NOM_UTI, PRENOM_UTI, TEL_UTI),
    constraint AK_COURR_UTI unique(COURRIEL_UTI),
    constraint FK_NOM_UTILISATEUR_UTI foreign key(NOM_UTILISATEUR) references
    TP2_ITEM_FAVORI(NOM_UTILISATEUR));
```

Comment: You need a `GO` statement between your two table creates so that the first table exists when you try and reference it in the second table.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using, I suspect Its Oracle SQL not MS SQL Server

Comment: Yes, it is Oracle SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key needs to be a primary key or unique column of another table: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02270.php.

In `TP2_UTILISATEUR`, you references `TP2_ITEM_FAVORI(NOM_UTILISATEUR)` as a foreign key, but `NOM_UTILISATEUR` is not the primary key of `TP2_ITEM_FAVORI`. `TP2_ITEM_FAVORI`'s primary key is `(NOM_UTILISATEUR, NO_ITEM)`.

Resolution is to change `TP2_ITEM_FAVORI`'s primary key to `NOM_UTILISATEUR` instead of both columns.

Comment: I understand, but if I don't change the `TP2_ITEM_FAVORI`'s primary key, then I can't make a foreign key constraint. So, how could I keep the same data for both tables ?

Comment: They are different tables. What do you mean by "keep the same data"? Changing the primary key does not change the data, right?

Comment: I found out my mistake, I have made the foreign key constraint in the wrong table -.-